# Получить ключи по булевому значению

Tags: python

Просьба, подсказать, как корректно получить ключи по значению, при условие что значения является булевыми

имею:

```
dictr = {'choice': {'ty2': True, 'rt24': False, '89': False}}
```

к примеру, вывести ключи, где значение True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простейшее, вот так захардкодить

```py
dictr = {'choice': {'ty2': True, 'rt24': False, '89': False}}
for key, value in dictr["choice"].items():
  if value:
    print(key)
```

вывод

```
ty2
```

а дальше от ваших целей и желаний

Answer (score 2):

можно сделать так:

```
dictr = {'choice': {'ty2': True, 'rt24': False, '89': False}}

value = True
res = [item[0] for item in dictr['choice'].items() if item[1] == value]

print(res)
```

если же нужна возможность вложенного обхода ВСЕГО словаря, то нужно просто будет создать аналогичную рекурсивную функцию

Comment: `res = [item[0] for item in dictr['choice'].items() if item[1] ]` так вроде тоже будет работать

Comment: будет, но автор как пример привел True, а если надо найти какую-то строку и т.д., т.е. значение может быть любым, поэтому я и написал более универсально чтобы видно было что менять

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал так:

```
dictr = {'choice': {'ty2': True, 'rt24': False, '89': False}}
res = {dictr_key: [key for key, val in dictr_val.items() if val] for dictr_key, dictr_val in dictr.items()}
print(res) # {'choice': ['ty2']}
```

Answer (score 1):

почти то же самое:

```
dictr = {'choice': {'ty2': True, 'rt24': False, '89': False}}
d = dictr['choice']
res = [k for k in d if d[k]]
```